# How to define specific actions for each item in a listview

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, listview

Well, so my listview has some rows and in these there's a text view that has to be modified by two buttons that also are in the row. The text view is a number (0) and one button increments this number and another one decreases it.

The problem is that when I increment or decrease the number of one of the items in my list, this number doesn't stay in its row and moves to the others when I scroll up and down. If you didn't understand this, here's a video of what happens: https://drive.google.com/open?id=11UYnu-sebZcbUIiG9oLoXtF8UeP1PAuv

So, how could I make that these numbers stay in their place? This is the code

**CartListActivity.java**

```js
public class CartListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView userList;
    UserCustomAdapter userAdapter;
    ArrayList<User> userArray = new ArrayList<User>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart_list);

        /**
         * add item in arraylist
         */
        userArray.add(new User("Olives verdes", "1,20€", "Aperitius", "0"));
        userArray.add(new User("Olives negres", "1,30€", "Aperitius", "0"));
        userArray.add(new User("Cogombrets", "1,80€", "Aperitius","0"));
        userArray.add(new User("Patates Lay's", "1,19€", "Aperitius","0"));
        userArray.add(new User("Potet", "0,95€", "Bebè","0"));
        userArray.add(new User("Biberó", "3,85€", "Bebè","0"));
        userArray.add(new User("Tovalloletes", "1,10€", "Bebè","0"));
        userArray.add(new User("Perxes de nadó", "1,95€", "Bebè","0"));
        /**
         * set item into adapter
         */
        userAdapter = new UserCustomAdapter(CartListActivity.this, R.layout.view_row,
                userArray);
        userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        userList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        /**
         * get on item click listener
         */
        userList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    final int position, long id) {
                Log.i("List View Clicked", "**********");
                Toast.makeText(CartListActivity.this,
                        "List View Clicked:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**User.java**

```js
public class User {
    String name;
    String price;
    String category;
    String quantity;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String address) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public User(String name, String address, String location, String quantity) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.category = category;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

}
```

**UserCustomAdapter.java**

```js
public class UserCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<User> data = new ArrayList<User>();

    public UserCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                             ArrayList<User> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        UserHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new UserHolder();
            holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.textPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.textCategory = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            holder.textQuantity = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.quantityTxt);
            holder.btnEdit = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            holder.btnDelete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        User user = data.get(position);
        holder.textName.setText(user.getName());
        holder.textPrice.setText(user.getPrice());
        holder.textCategory.setText(user.getCategory());
        final UserHolder finalHolder = holder;
        holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String value1 = finalHolder.textQuantity.getText().toString();
                int a = Integer.parseInt(value1);

                if(a <= 99) {
                    int sum = a + 1;

                    Log.i("Edit Button Clicked", "**********");
                    finalHolder.textQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
                }
            }
        });
        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    String value2 = finalHolder.textQuantity.getText().toString();
                    int a = Integer.parseInt(value2);

                    if(a > 0) {
                        int substract = a - 1;
                        Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "**********");
                        finalHolder.textQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(substract));
                    }
            }
        });
        return row;

    }

    static class UserHolder {
        TextView textName;
        TextView textPrice;
        TextView textCategory;
        TextView textQuantity;
        Button btnEdit;
        Button btnDelete;
    }
}
```

Comment: please set the value when you click on + and -. e.g user.setQuantity(a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the userQuantity at each call of getView and update your the value of quantity in the User object when edit or delete is clicked. Add the lines like below:

```
    final User user = data.get(position);   // CHANGE TO FINAL
    holder.textName.setText(user.getName());
    holder.textPrice.setText(user.getPrice());
    holder.textCategory.setText(user.getCategory());
    holder.textQuantity.setText(user.getQuantity()); // ADD THIS LINE
    final UserHolder finalHolder = holder;
    holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String value1 = finalHolder.textQuantity.getText().toString();
            int a = Integer.parseInt(value1);

            if(a <= 99) {
                int sum = a + 1;

                Log.i("Edit Button Clicked", "**********");
                user.setQuantity(Integer.toString(sum)); // ADD THIS LINE
                finalHolder.textQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
            }
        }
    });
    holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                String value2 = finalHolder.textQuantity.getText().toString();
                int a = Integer.parseInt(value2);

                if(a > 0) {
                    int substract = a - 1;
                    Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "**********");

                     user.setQuantity(Integer.toString(subtract)); // ADD THIS LINE

                 finalHolder.textQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(substract));
                }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed my problem